# The parameter 'buttonText' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to compile a calculator app, from a flutter template. I'm getting this error.

```
lib/buttons.dart:13:46: Error: The parameter 'buttonText' can't have a value of 'null' 
because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
MyButton({this.color, this.textColor, this.buttonText, this.buttontapped});
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

So now I'm trying to add a value for the button text, but I'm having issues. This is what I tried, the last line is what I added, the rest were there before.

```
// declaring variables
final color;
final textColor;
final String buttonText;
final buttontapped;
buttonText = Whatever,
```

Answer (score 1):

buttonText is a string so Whatever needs to be wrapped in ''

ie

```
final color;
final textColor;
final buttonText;
final buttonTapped;
```

then

```
myButton({this.buttonText = 'whatever'})
```

or dont declare it at all until it is used

```
myButton({required this.buttonText})
```

and remove the separate declaration of it.

Comment: if that doesnt work mind sharing the entirety of the code?

Comment: I changed it but the problem persists. I'll send you a screenshot if I can on stackoverflow. https://imgur.com/a/22UqXOH

Comment: You need to add the default value on your constructor, not at variable declaration time

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the required statement to your class contstructor.

```
    //Constructor
    MyButton({this.color, this.textColor, required this.buttonText, this.buttontapped})
```

Or provide your default value.

```
//Constructor
    MyButton({this.color, this.textColor,  this.buttonText = 'what ever', this.buttontapped})
```

Or make your field optional, I don't think you want this!

```
final color;
final textColor;
String? buttonText;
final buttonTapped;
```